# Memory error in python

Tags: python, performance, memory-management

I am writing a code which returns something like 1^k + 2^k + 3^k......n-1 where k be any number.Below is my code.I am getting a memory error.How do I optimise it.
Sample test case for wrong error:

1
10000000000000000 400

```
#!/bin/python    
    import sys



def highwayConstruction(n, k):
    # Complete this function
    sum=0
    for i in range(1,n-1):
        sum+=(n-i)**k
    return sum    

q = int(raw_input().strip())
print "Qw"
for a0 in xrange(q):
    n, k = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
    n, k = [long(n), int(k)]
    result = highwayConstruction(n, k)
    print result
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `xrange` instead of `range`.
They both provide a way to generate a list of integers for you to use. The only difference is that range returns a Python list object and xrange returns an xrange object. You get the `MemoryError` because the list you are trying to generate is too big.
I tried running it with `xrange` and it didn't crash. I waited for about 30 minutes and it's still running.

Comment: but now it gives me a timeout error.

Comment: This probably means your cpu can't handle this calculation.

Comment: is there any other way to do this like bitwise implementation.